# Join and Include in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query of linq to entities. The problem is that it doesn't seem to load the "Tags" relation even though i have included a thing for it. It works fine if i do not join on tags but i need to do that.

```
            var items = from i in db.Items.Include("Tags")
                        from t in i.Tags
                        where t.Text == text
                        orderby i.CreatedDate descending
                        select i;
```

Is there any other way to ask this query? Maybe split it up or something?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, the Include contradicts the where. Include says, "Load all tags." The where says, "Load some tags." When there is a contradiction between the query and Include, the query will always win.

To return **all** tags from **any** item with **at least** one tag == text:

```
        var items = from i in db.Items.Include("Tags")
                    where i.Tags.Any(t => t.Text == text)
                    orderby i.CreatedDate descending
                    select i;
```

(Untested, as I don't have your DB/model)

Here's [a really good, free book on LINQ](http://www.mindviewinc.com/Books/CSharp/Index.php).

Comment: Any suggestions on how to write it in some other way so i can get the tags and do a condition on them. It would be kind of simple in regular SQL.

Comment: Do you want to include ALL tags from ANY item with AT LEAST one tag == text?