# Linq, emulating joins, and the Include method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, join

I'm looking into an issue that is related to...
[Join and Include in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework)

Basically the following query returns the list of "Property" objects the current user has permissions ( ACLs ) to view.

```
IQueryable<Property> currPropList 
                = from p in ve.Property
                                .Include("phyAddress")
                                .Include("Contact")
                  from a in ve.ACLs
                  from u in ve.Account
                  from gj in ve.ObjectGroupJoin
                  where u.username == currUsername              // The username
                        && (a.Account.id == u.id                // The ACLs
                            && a.objType == (int)ObjectType.Group)
                        && (gj.ObjectGroup.id == a.objId        // The groups
                            && gj.objId == p.id)                // The properties
                  select p;
```

The query returns the correct list of properties and in large works fine.

But the "Include" calls in the linq query above does not load the objects.  If I call "Load()" explicitly after the LINQ query then the objects load.

The [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework) suggested that there may be a conflict between the "Include" call and the where clause.  How can that be the case?

But at any rate, how can I restructure this query to load the "phyAddress" and "Contract" members?  Specifically, I'd only like to load the members on *returned* objects, not all the "phyAddress" and "Contact" objects in the database.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I've tracked down the issue to the use of multiple *from* clauses

This works...

```
IQueryable<Property> currPropList 
            = from p in ve.Property
                            .Include("phyAddress")
              select p;
```

And the "phyAddress" member is loaded.

But this doesn't work...

```
IQueryable<Property> currPropList 
            = from p in ve.Property
                            .Include("phyAddress")
              from a in ve.ACLs
              select p;
```

Basically the *Include* call is ignored when there are multiple *from* clauses.  Does anyone know of a work around for this?

**Edit 2**

One workaround is to cast the *IQueryable* result as a *ObjectQuery* and get the include off of that.  But I would like to prevent the second roundtrip to the database I am assuming this causes.

Eg.  This works....

```
IQueryable<Property> currPropList 
        = ((from p in ve.Property
          from a in ve.ACLs
          select p) as ObjectQuery<Property>).Include("phyAddress");
```

Is there a way to do this with only a single query?

**Edit 3**

No second query because of *deferred execution* [ http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx.  So edit 2 would be the solution.

Comment: It does only one sql query. There is no second roundtrip. If you are not sure, you should look at SQL Server Profiler.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Include... if you do something that changes the shape of the query (i.e. from from) then the Include is lost there are simple enough workarounds though:

1. you can wrap the include around the query, see [Tip 22 - How to make include really include](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx).
2. or you can get everything you need in the select clause and let relationship fixup do the job for you. i.e.

   ```
   var x = from p in ve.Property  
           from a in ve.ACLs  
           select new {p,p.phyAddress};  

   var results = x.AsEnumerable().Select(p => p.p);
   ```

Now results is an enumeration of property entities, but each one has it's phyAddress loaded, as a side-effect of the initial request for the phyAddress, and EF's relationship fixup.