# Why does EF lose include data when performing a "from" join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

If I have a LINQ expression like this to pull a user table and related data. This query gives me a populated object graph as expected:

```
    var query = from u in Context.Users
                    .Include("EventRegistrations")
                    .Include("State")
                select u;
```

However, if I add another related navigation property as a 'from', and even if I don't do anything with it, I only get the single object data in my result without the include data.

```
    var query = from u in Context.Users
                    .Include("EventRegistrations")
                    .Include("State")
                from ur in u.UserRoles
                select u;
```

Why would this be? I want to use "ur" in the above expression in a where clause, but it eliminates my ability to get the included table data.

Comment: Just as a point of interest you can also use the lambda include syntax so it is compile time safe, ie `.include(u=>u.State)` you will also need a `using System.Data.Entity;` statement

Comment: Why do you add `from ur in u.UserRoles`? You don't need it to use `UserRoles` in where clause.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework. I agree with@LukLed. I suggest to show the full query you want to perform, there is probably an alternative solution that doesn't need the second `from`.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because you haven't included UserRoles

```
var query = from u in Context.Users
                .Include("EventRegistrations")
                .Include("State")
                .Include("UserRoles")
            from ur in u.UserRoles
            select u;
```

Comment: I doubt that this solves the problem. Why should adding the Include for UserRoles suddenly cause the EventRegistrations and State to be loaded?