# Entity Framework Many to Many works but Include does not

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have a typical many-to-many relationship with these 3 tables

```
[Post] (
  [PostId] int, (PK)
  [Content] nvarchar(max)
   ...
)

[Tag] (
  [TagId] int, (PK)
  [Name] nvarchar
  ...
)

[TagPost] (
  [TagId] int, (PK, FK)
  [PostId] int (PK, FK)
)
```

And, TagId and PostId are the PK and FK set on the tables accordingly etc.  Then I have these classes and mapping in c#

```
public class Post {
    public Post()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; private set; }
}

public class Tag {
    public Tag()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; private set; }
}

internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("Post");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().ToTable("Tag");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Tags)
            .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("TagPost");
            x.MapLeftKey("PostId");
            x.MapRightKey("TagId");
        });
    }
```

Then I have this code to query them

```
var list = (from p in ctx.Posts.Include(p => p.Tags)
            from t in p.Tags
            where ... // some of my filter conditions
            select p).ToList();
```

This join does return the posts I was looking for, however the returned posts don't their associated tags filled in even though I have the Include there.  Could someone help point out what I'm missing so that I could have the tags also return with the posts?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double `from` is a manual `Join` which causes the `Include` to be ignored as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794283/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-loading). `Include` is also ignored for other LINQ methods [like grouping and projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474951/entity-framework-include-is-not-working).

Relationship fixup generally does not work for many-to-many relationships, only for relationships which have at least one single reference at one of the ends - one-to-many or one-to-one. If you project the `Posts` and related `Tags` into another type (anonymous or named) the data will be loaded correctly but because the relationship is many-to-many EF won't create the relationship in memory automatically so that the `post.Tags` collection will stay empty.

To get the `Include` working you must remove the second `from` from your query and apply the `where` clause directly to the `Post` entity parameter, for example like so:

```
var list = (from p in ctx.Posts.Include(p => p.Tags)
            where p.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == 1)
            select p).ToList();
```

The filter by a `Tag` property is specified in the expression passed into `.Any` which is an expression with a `Tag` (`t`) as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try selecting everything into an anonymous object (something like this)

```
var list = (
        from p in ctx.Posts
        from t in p.Tags
        where ... // some of my filter conditions
        select new {
            Posts = p,
            Tags = p.Tags
        })
    .ToList();
```

---

Based on the feedback to my initial answer and the fact that EF can find the related entities but it is failing to populate the `Tags` collection I believe the issue lies in the definition of the Tags entity in the Post class.

Try removing the `Hashset<>` initialiser from the constructors and `private` from the set declaration:

```
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you qujck! I see you are returning a list of this anonymous type, but how do I convert that to List<Post> with each post that has its List<Tag>?

Comment: Fix-up should automatically populate the `Tag` references in each `Post`.

Comment: I debugged and looked at the Posts in the returned list, by doing list.Select(a=>a.Posts) and it doesn't have the tags populated in them.

Comment: Is the `Tags` property of the anonymous type filled?

Comment: Yes, the Tags in the anonymous type is filled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26676/discussion-between-ray247-and-qujck)