# Entity Framework - Include multiple level properties with self reference

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've just learned how to include multpiple level properties with Entity Framework ( on this thread : [Entity Framework - Include Multiple Levels of Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties)).
But things fail when I'm attempting to include a collection containing the base entity.

Here is my base class :

```
public partial class Artiste
{
    public Artiste()
    {
        this.Parutions = new HashSet<Parution>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Parution> Parutions { get; set; }
}
```

And my second class :

```
public partial class Parution
{
    public Parution()
    {
        this.Artistes = new HashSet<Artiste>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Artiste> Artistes { get; set; }
}
```

Artiste have many Parutions. Parution have many Artistes.
When I'm querying an Artiste while including his Parutions :

```
dbQuery.Include(a => a.Parutions);
```

In the Parutions Artistes, I've got only the queried Artiste (one Artiste). I don't get the other Artistes.
I've tried this :

```
dbQuery.Include(a => a.Parutions.Select(p => p.Artistes));
```

But it gives some error that Artiste is already loaded.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Many to Many works but Include does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556134/entity-framework-many-to-many-works-but-include-does-not)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate since the Artiste.Parutions are filled.
The problem is with the Artiste.Parutions.Artistes collection here.