# verify null entity one to one mapping Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one

I have two tables :

Table **AnnonceVImg**: Id, dateModif,

Table **AnnonceVTxt**: Id, dateModif, AnnonceVImg_Id

I want to display only the images which are not yet linked to an AnnonceVTxt, but since I don't have the AnnonceVTxt_id in AnnonceVImg I don't know how to add this condition.

Here is my controller

```
public PartialViewResult ListAnnonce(DateTime dateParution, long IdJournal)
    {
        using (var db = new Bd_scanitEntities())
        {
            List<ScanITAPP.ImgOrgSet> images = new List<ImgOrgSet>();
            images = db.JournalSet.Find(IdJournal).ImgOrgSet.Where(i => i.dateParution == dateParution).ToList();
            List<ScanITAPP.AnnonceVImgSet> annoncesVimg = new List<AnnonceVImgSet>();
            foreach (var img in images)
            {
                annoncesVimg.AddRange(db.ImgOrgSet.Find(img.Id).AnnonceVImgSet.ToList());
            }

            //IEnumerable<ScanITAPP.AnnonceVImgSet> annonces;
            ViewBag.IdJournal = dateParution;
            ViewData["dateParution"] = dateParution.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            AnnonceVTxtSet annTxt = new AnnonceVTxtSet();
            annTxt.Id = 0;
            AnnonceVImgSet annImg = db.AnnonceVImgSet.Find(1);
            annTxt.AnnonceVImgSet = annImg;

            return PartialView("_ListAnnonceImg", annoncesVimg.OrderBy(i => i.dateSaisi).Distinct().ToList());
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to include AnnonceVTxt table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework