# Entity framework `AsNoTracking` is not working with anonymous projection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, anonymous

In the below snipped i try to fetch data using `Anonymous Projection` and i would like do not track the `entities` that is fetched.

*Note : i have already gone through existing stack question,yet unable to find a working solution for me*

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
     db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
     db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

     var myprojection = db.Table1
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(gh=>gh.Table2) //Update
                        .Include(gh=>gh.Table3) //Update
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            table1= x,
                            table2= x.Table2.Where(g => Some Condition),

                            table3= x.Table3.Where(g=>Some Condition)
                        })
                        .ToList();

    var result = myprojection.Select(g =>g.table1).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

> When i use`AsNoTracking()` data from the inner tables (table2,3) is lost during the conversion at this line `var result = myprojection.Select(g =>g.table1).FirstOrDefault();`

**Edit**

> If i remove `AsNoTracking()` everything works fine.

**1) How to use `projection` and `AsNoTracking` in entity framework correctly ?**

**2) Any other option to remove tracking of this query?**

Is there any possible workarounds?

Comment: Why did you set LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled  to false?

Comment: I have both `WCF` and direct database connection. So there will be circular serialization if enable lazyloading

Comment: You'll have to use inner join instead if you want to filter those tables

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416847/join-and-include-in-entity-framework?rq=1 i'm fetching similar to this

Answer (score 2):

> When i useAsNoTracking() data from the inner tables (table2,3) is lost during the conversion at this line var result = myprojection.Select(g =>g.table1).FirstOrDefault();

Your selecting Table1, into an anonymous type you will not have access to table2 or table3 although the navigation properties are they they will not map. Entities loses it relationships when you select into anonymous type you need to select table two and three or don't pull it into an anonymous type.

Just put your wheres directly in the table one where and then make your call

```
 var myprojection = db.Table1.Join(db.Table2.Where(x => yourcondition), 
                                     t1 => t1.id, t2 => t2.t1id, (t1, t2) => t1 );
```

then you have to do another join for table3

but your probably better just making the call in two queries

Comment: I'm using `ef4` this is not compiling in my scenario. Here `Table1` to Table2 has 1 to many relationship. `Cannot convert IEnumberable<T> to bool exception`

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, it does not make sense to use
>   `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` and `AsNoTracking()`
>   at the same time.

If you use `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` change tracking will turn off for all queries.

But your problem with inner tables 2 and 3 is not caused by `AsNoTracking()`.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Turn off lazy loading and i guess it's good for performance reason. If turn it on, you will get expected result, but Entity Framework will make additional SQL query to Data Base for every row in **myprojection** result. You should better do the following:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
   db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

   var myprojection = db.Table1
                    .Include(x=>x.Table2).Include(x=>x.Table3)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        table1= x,
                        table2= x.Table2.Where(g => Some Condition),
                        table3= x.Table3.Where(g=>Some Condition)
                    })
                    .ToList();

  var result = myprojection.Select(g =>g.table1).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

> Using `.Include(x=>x.Table2).Include(x=>x.Table3)` in your query will
>   force Entity Framerwork to load related Table2 and Table3 for one
>   query to Data Base.

Comment: Include will not work for custom projections. So `Table2/3` Data wont be loaded in `table1` property. But it will be loaded in properties `table2` and `table3` without any `Include`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToList()` for your navigation properties. Note that it will still projekt in the DB. (**EF6**)

```
// ..
table2 = x.Table2.Where(g => Some Condition).ToList(),
```

Update:

With **EF4** you probably need to map `table2` manually:

```
 table2 = x.Table2.Where(g => CONDITION).Select(x => new {Foo = x.Bar}),
```

Comment: It will throw exception `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method`

Comment: Is your "Some Condition" simple expression? While `ToList` definitely works in EF6. Try to remove condition, will you still get the exception?

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention, I'm using EF4, The condition is pretty simple `(SomeVariable == SomeVariable && SomeBoolean)`

Comment: Oh, try to make additional select for `Table2`. See my update.

Comment: Additionally, you can see also any time what SQL statement is generated from your query. Without calling the last `ToList()`: `((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString()`

Comment: Sorry, then I have no clue for you here, while such thing for sure works with EF6, while I offen do the same things. And, if you say, it works without `AsNoTracking`, then use it without, you can disable `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, and together with falsy `ProxyCreationEnabled` it would be not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
    {
         db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
         db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

         var myprojection = db.Table1 
                            //.AsNoTracking()  //remove.AsNoTracking() from here
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                table1= x,
                                table2= x.Table2.Where(g => Some Condition),
                                table3= x.Table3.Where(g=>Some Condition)
                            })
                            .AsNoTracking()//add .AsNoTracking() here
                            .ToList();    

        var result = myprojection.Select(g =>g.table1).FirstOrDefault();    
    }
```

NOTE: I dont try this. Just an idea, i hope this helps to you

Comment: I think that it will not work. _AsNoTracking_ will not modify _Table1_ but it will return "a new query where the entities returned will not be cached in the System.Data.Entity.DbContext."