# Anonymous type select object and its children

Tags: c#, linq

```
Categoires
    .Where(c => c.ID == 18)
    .Include("Products.ProductPrices")
    .Select(c => new
                        {
                            ID = c.ID,
                            Name = c.Name, // other properties
                            ProductAndPrices = c.Products.ProductPrice,
                            // from above what I really want is Products + there prices
                        })
```

I am here having a conceptual problem with this code from above,

```
ProductAndPrices = c.Products.ProductPrice,
```

I can do this,

```
ProductAndPrices = c.Products,
```

but not this,

```
ProductAndPrices = c.Products.ProductPrice,
```

**Problem**

Using linqpad I can see my query is working and have all data until **Incude("Products.ProductPrices")** but when I try to create an anonymous object and flat it doesn't lets me.

Please note Products can have many prices.

**Edit**

This works for me,

```
ProductAndPrices = c.Products.SelectMany(p => p.ProductPrice),
```

But above only then gives list of ProductPrices, it doesn't include Products columns at all,

What I really want is product columns + its children (which are Prices)

ProductPrice is a collection as well, it is list of prices history for a product.

Comment: You need to edit your question and show your classes : `Product` class and `ProductPrice` class and `Categories` class

Comment: I'm guessing that `Products` is a collection of `Product` that have a `ProductPrice` property.   So you could do `c.Products.Select(p =>  p.ProductPrice)` to get the prices, but it's not clear what you want `ProductAndPrice` to be.

Comment: @juharr I just added bit more explanation, please check if it makes any sense, it's 1 to many relationship between parent and child... ProductPrice is a collection as well, it is list of prices history for a product

Comment: In other words, Product itself + it's childrens

Comment: @Mathematics Have you tried this `c.Products.Select(p => new { Product = p, Prices = p.ProductPrice })` ? - I have no idea how the provider is going to translate this.

Comment: @Mathematics if you are projecting , the include doesn't work. See more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/416899/1876572

Comment: @user3185569 yes that's it but I want list of Prices as property of Products not as separate objects :)

Comment: It will help others if you can post the structures of Category, Product, and ProductPrice.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the prices like this:

```
ProductAndPrices = c.Products.Select(p => new { Product = p, Prices = p.ProductPrice })
```

Comment: thank you, but won't above will only give me ProductPrices not Products + ProductPrices ? I did tried above with SelectMany

Comment: @Mathematics then you need to edit your question and show your classes : `Product` class and `ProductPrice` class

Answer (score 1):

`Include` is always ignored if you use a projection. But you can get the required data by:

```
Categories
    .Where(c => c.ID == 18)
    .Include("Products.ProductPrices")
    .Select(c => new
                {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Name = c.Name, // other properties
                    Products = c.Products
                                .Select(p => new
                                {
                                    Product = p,
                                    // Or maybe various Product properties
                                    ProductPrices = p.ProductPrice
                                })
                })
```

Comment: I want exactly same but Products object has 2 properties whereas I want it to have product's properties + Prices as chilrens

Comment: With this code, you'll see that the products do have their `ProductPrices` collections populated, because EF executes *relationship fixup*, i.e. it auto-populates navigation properties by entities that are available in the context's cache.

Comment: One more thing: in this case, you should prevent lazy loading, otherwise EF will try to lazy-load `Products.ProductPrices` when you address it, even when the context is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines

```
Categories
    .Where(c => c.ID == 18)
    .Include("Products.ProductPrices").SelectMany(c=> p.Products.ProductPrices, (parent, child) => 
                                                                new { Product = parent, ProductAndPrices = child});
```